# How to convert a zoo object in a ts object in order to use strucchange

Tags: r, zoo

Ok. I´ve tried several foruns and threads, but I couldn't find this. I imported my database to R using this:

```
teste <- read.zoo("bitcoin2.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",",  format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Which worked fine. My xyplot gave me the right plot. So I tried to convert it to ts in order to use strucchange and other outlier/breakpoints packages.

```
aba <- as.ts(zoo(z$Weighted_Price))
```

When I did it, it seems to have been lost the index time. The plot still has the same shape, but the X-axis doesn't look as a regular time series plot.

Anyway, I´ve tried the strucchange. After loading it, I made this simple test:

```
 test<-breakpoints(teste$Weighted_Price~1)
```

But R returned me:

```
Error in my.RSS.table[as.character(i), 3:4] <- c(pot.index[opt], break.RSS[opt]) : 
  replacement has length zero
```

I presume my mistake is that the coercion from zoo to ts was not correct. Any help would be great.